# When oracle virtualbox are set, How to get local ip address in python

Tags: python, ip

--

I've searched to find out how to get my local ip address using python. (my python version is 3.4) And there is an answer. That answer says:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

And it works. script said my ip address is 192.168.56.1 . But my local (=internal) ip  address is 192.168.0.100 .

So, What was that ip address? It was an ip address of 'Virtualbox Host-Only Network' which was installed when I setup virtualbox a week ago. (Virtualbox's version is 5.0) I have now 2 network adapter, one is 'Virtualbox Host-Only Network' and the other is local area network

When I turn that 'Virtualbox Host-Only Network' off in network panel. python script says my ip address is 192.168.0.100 which I want.

How to get my ip address '192.168.0.100' regardless of disabling 'Virtualbox Host-Only Network'?
( I really don't want to turn off 'Virtualbox Host-Only Network'. )

Comment: Can you post the output of ifconfig command please? ([Jhun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5179678/jhun) asked this in an answer because of <50 rep)

Comment: Thank you for your interest, and sorry for my carelessness of writing my development interfaces. I am using windows 7 and my ipconfig says...'Ethernet adapter local area connection' is 192.168.0.100 and 'Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network' is 192.168.56.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a module called **[netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces)** to get the ip address of whatever network interfaces are available on your machine.

You can install **netifaces** with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) if you have pip installed on your system.

```
pip install netifaces
```

**An example from the command line on a linux system:**

My machine has my regular network interface on `eth0` and an alias network interface on `eth0:0` (this would be similar to your virtualbox host-only network interface, but the name would be different.)

Getting a listing of the network interfaces available on your machine via the python interpreter:

```
(stackoverflow)[root@joeyoung.io stackoverflow]# python

>>> import netifaces
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0', 'eth0:0']
```

Getting more information about my regular network interface `eth0`:

```
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')
{17: [{'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'addr': '52:54:00:0d:4d:36'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '159.107.29.255', 'netmask': '255.255.254.0', 'addr': '159.107.28.65'}]}
```

I'm only interested in the Internet Protocal Address Family so lets narrow down the results using `AF_INET` as a filter:

```
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_INET]
[{'broadcast': '159.107.29.255', 'netmask': '255.255.254.0', 'addr': '159.107.28.65'}]
```

This gives me back a list with 1 entry.  That entry contains a dictionary.  I want to get the value represented by the `addr` key in order to get the ip address of my `eth0` interface:

```
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']
'159.107.28.65'
```

`159.107.28.65` is the local IP address of my eth0 interface.

We can do the same steps above to get my alias IP address on `eth0:0` as well:

```
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0:0')
{2: [{'broadcast': '192.168.13.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '192.168.13.2'}]}
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0:0')[netifaces.AF_INET]
[{'broadcast': '192.168.13.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '192.168.13.2'}]
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0:0')[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']
'192.168.13.2'
```

Comment: Thank you jlyoung! The problem is solved. As you adviced, I used netifaces module and now I can get my network information which I want. I am using python in windows 7. So there is a difference in result of 'netifaces.interfaces()'. In windows the result set is shown like this..

['{F4D07299-32E8-4231-A089-41A269434941}', '{0B70EBE0-3A72-43A8-A4A4-8BB506A4F053}', '{846EE342-7039-11DE-9D20-806E6F6E6963}', '{026BC1E3-1EB4-4D50-9253-CE0AFE398AAA}']

it is a dictionary type. and I can reference it as follows. 

netifaces.ifaddresses(netifaces.interfaces()[0])

Answer (score 1):

This sequence works for me on a Linux virtual machine:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53))
print s.getsockname()[0]
```

result:

```
10.112.54.236
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. I am now developing in windows. I don't certain this is the cause an error or not, but I've tried your code and It doesn't work. Before everything, sorry for my carelessness write my dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Let me document what I have done.
I ran a Linux VM from a Windows 10 host using Oracle VirtualBox.

- `192.168.1.46` was the IP address of the Windows 10 host, i.e., VM host.
- `10.0.2.15` was the IP address of the VM to access the Internet. This was automatically created by Oracle VirtualBox.  NAT was used to translate TCP/IP messages between the Internet and the VM Host or VM.
- `192.168.56.102` and `192.168.56.1` were the IP addresses created by Oracle VirtualBox when I manually created a host-only adapter. I could login to the Linux VM from the Windows 10 host.

[image]

I used `psutil` (a Python library) and `ip` (Linux command) to get the IP addresses.

1. To get the IP address of the Windows 10 host accessing the Internet,

   ```
   python -c "import psutil as p; print(p.net_if_addrs()['Wi-Fi'][1].address)"
   ```

   You may need to rename the interface name ('Wi-Fi' in my case)
2. To get the IP address of the Windows 10 host accessing the VM,

   ```
   python -c "import psutil as p; print(p.net_if_addrs()['VirtualBox Host-Only Network'][1].address)"
   ```

   You may need to rename the interface name ('VirtualBox Host-Only Network' in my case)
3. To get the IP address of the Linux VM to access the Internet

   ```
   ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $7}'
   ```
4. To get the IP address of the Linux VM to access `192.168.56.1`

   ```
   ip route get 192.168.56.1 | awk '{print $5}'
   ```