# First computer doesn't receive UDP packet sent from Second computer

Tags: python, sockets, udp, firewall

Today i was trying Python's socket module, but i failed to send/recieve from one PC to another.

At first i tried doing everything on single PC:

Receiver:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5003
s.bind((ip, port))
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print(data, addr)
```

Sender:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ip = # I wrote ip manually from socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5003
s.sendto("Hello!", (ip, port))
```

Doing first script on first command line and other on second, on single PC, would work fine. But doing from one PC to another would not.

Whenever i executed Receiver script on first PC, and Sender script on second PC, there were no updates, First PC couldn't receive packet.

Also sending packet from PC2 to PC1 works, but vice versa doesn't.
Operating systems:

PC2 = Windows 8.1 64 bit;
PC1 = Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 64 bit;

I have also tried adding outbound rule in Windows firewall, allowing all connections for specific port.

---

What could the problem be? Is it because of firewall? If not then am i doing this incorrectly?

Comment: have you tried changing the port number?

Comment: Can you ping the other PC?  Are they on same IP network?  Same subnet mask?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Strange, sending packet from PC2 to PC1 on port 3020 works, but from PC1 to PC2 doesn't.

Comment: @ade1e The first numbers: `xxx.xx` of both IPv4 addresses are same, but last numbers are different.

Comment: It might be windows firewall blocking the connectivity on PC2.  You may need to add an exception to allow this.

Comment: @ade1e I have tried adding outbound rule, and allowing all connections on port 3020, but it didn't work.

Comment: first try without firewall - turn off firewall. If it will work then you will search correct rules in firewall. It may need not only outbound rule but inbounce rule and not only with port 3020.

Comment: @furas I turned off firewall and executed scripts right after, still no update unfortunately.

Comment: do you get any error message ? do you use correct IP in both scripts - receiver IP in both script ?

Comment: It would just print out "4" after executing sender, and yes IP is the same.

Comment: maybe second conputer runs firewall too

Comment: @furas pf (OSX's firewall) doesn't block outgoing connections as I have read, + I have it disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found the problem:

**Short**:

`socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` contained `IPv4` address of VirtualBox. Wireless LAN adapter `IPv4` was different, and would receive UDP packet.

**Long**:

I was looking for Wireless Lan Adapter `IPv4` address in `ipconfig` would be same in `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`, but turns out
`socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` would give the address of VirtualBox Host-Only Network.

When i pinged the VM `IPv4` it would give timeout request, but after pinging real local `IPv4` it did work.

## Fix:

[When oracle virtualbox are set, How to get local ip address in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069628/when-oracle-virtualbox-are-set-how-to-get-local-ip-address-in-python)